# Titanium studio autocomplete for alloy does not work

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am a newbie to Titanium studio. Have started using Alloy. Have figured out that autocompletion works in alloy view xml file for a lot of tags.

However for a lot of tags like Button, Label... autocompletion is not available.

I have build 3.1.1.201306112235 of Titanium studio.. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your Alloy correctly installed?

```
$ alloy --version
```

You should get something like: `1.3.0`

You can try some of these:

- *Project > Clean*
- Update your Alloy
- Go to Titanium preferences, *Studio > Content Assist* and restore the defaults
- Install the latest Titanium Studio version.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me (not the OP, but have this problem).


- Alloy 1.3.1
- Project cleaned
- Studio > content assist restored
- Titanium Studio downloaded a few days ago


Titanium Studio, build: 3.2.1.201402041146
(c) Copyright 2012-2013 by Appcelerator, Inc.  All rights reserved.


Build: jenkins-titanium-rcp-master-95 (origin/master)
Date: 04 February 2014, 11:47:38

No dice still... :(

Comment: Text is not formatting right in my answer.  Long and short, some combination of the above *did* help, but only after restarting TS.